# Search for Value and Return Column Header

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet in excel that has a director at the top of each column, with all of his/her employee's ID numbers below him/her in that column. Some have 3 employees (rows) below them, others have 300 employees (rows), so the worksheet is not a symmetric matrix. Each employee ID only appears once on this worksheet. This worksheet will also change frequently so I want the formula to be dynamic and capture the entire worksheet.

I have another worksheet with employee IDs on each row, and want to pull in the director for that employee. So, I need to search for their employee ID and return the value in the header of the column their ID is found in.

Any ideas on how to do this? I cant figure out how to do it with Index/Match or the COLUMN formula... im pretty stuck! Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this - it can be done as an array formula using index/match, but performance may be an issue: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/673515-finding-value-multiple-column-array-returning-column-header-excel-2003-a.html

Answer (score 1):

With Sheet1 like this:

[image: SO33089061 first example]

and an array entered formula such as:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:C$1,MAX(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$11=A2,COLUMN(A2:C11))))
```

in B2 and copied down to suit of another sheet the results should be:

[image: SO33089061 second example]

This is dynamic and, for me, quick BUT it will return a result even where there is no such employee in the range selected from Sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try closing it in like this?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:C$1,MAX(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$11=A2,COLUMN(A2:C11),0))))
```